# Getting transportation turnover as null when i filtered by Product nature

Tags: sql

I am pretty new to SQL. When i tried the following query i am getting sum as 0.

Can somebody explain me the problem of the query.

```
select sum(transportation_turnover)
from(
SELECT  top 10000 dd.tdt_order_number AS order_number,
              dd.tdt_date_to_ordered AS ordered_date,
              dd.frm_delivery_type AS delivery_type,
              dd.dyh_date_expected_delivery AS promised_delivery_date,
              dd.dyh_date_actual_shipment AS warehouse_pickup_time,
              dd.ctm_zip_code AS customer_zip_code,
              dd.tdt_date_to_returned AS date_of_return,
              ds.family_label as family,
              ds.dpt_label as department,
              ds.product_nature_label as product_nature,
              ds.mdl_num_model_r3 AS model_number,
              SUM(CASE WHEN dd.tdt_item_id = '2102120' THEN dd.f_to_tax_in ELSE 0 END) AS transportation_turnover, 
              SUM(dd.f_qty_item) as quantity,
              dd.tdt_type_detail as type,
              ds.mdl_label as model_name,
              but.but_name_business_unit as shipped_from
         FROM cds.f_delivery_detail_current dd
         INNER JOIN cds.d_sku ds ON dd.sku_idr_sku = ds.sku_idr_sku
         INNER JOIN cds.d_business_unit but ON dd.but_idr_business_unit_stock_origin= but.but_idr_business_unit
       WHERE dd.cnt_idr_country = 50
       AND   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dd.the_date_transaction) IN (2019,2020)
       GROUP BY order_number,
                ordered_date,
                delivery_type,
                promised_delivery_date,
                warehouse_pickup_time,
                customer_zip_code,
                date_of_return,
                family,
                department,
                product_nature,
                model_number,
                type,
                model_name,
                shipped_from
       ORDER BY order_number)
where type = 'sale'
```